# Automapper IQueryable error

Tags: c#, automapper

Trying to use IQueryable extensoins of Automapper.
The followng code:

```
class Program
{
    public class A { public string[] Strings { get; set; } }
    public class B { public string[] Lines { get; set; } }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>()
              .ForMember(m => m.Lines, action => action.MapFrom(src => src.Strings));

        IQueryable<A> qa = (new List<A>() {new A() {Strings = new string[0]}}).AsQueryable();
        IQueryable<B> b = qa.Project().To<B>(); // error is here
    }
}
```

gives error "Sequence contains no elements". This is because this line:

```
          .ForMember(m => m.Lines, action => action.MapFrom(src => src.Strings));
```

What am i doing wrong? I know there is a simplier solution for this particular case but i meet this trouble everytime i use collections in ".MapFrom" method.
STack trace says:

> at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
>   at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.CreateMapExpression(Type typeIn, Type
>   typeOut)    at
>   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.<CreateMapExpression>b__9[TSource,TDestination](TypePair
>   tp)    at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)    at
>   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.CreateMapExpression[TSource,TDestination]()
>
>   at ConsoleApplication1.ProjectionExpression`1.ToTResult in
>   d:\Work\Misc\VS\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line
>   57    at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   d:\Work\Misc\VS\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line
>   21    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String[] args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

so it performs First() at some point. Why? How to solve it?
Thanks.